# Can anyone explain Quran 21:30?

Tags: tafseer, creation

In Holy Quran 21:30 it says that the universe and the earth were once joined together and were then separated apart. But the universe is older than the earth.

Answer (score 1):

If I separate butter from cream will you tell me cream is older than butter?

Butter and cream are as old as milk.

Similarly earth and rest of universe were part of a large mass.